# how to use namespace in @loadable/server

Tags: reactjs, server-side-rendering, code-splitting, loadable-component

The @loadable/server docs - https://loadable-components.com/docs/api-loadable-server/
give an option for using namespace in chunkExtractor as an option if you have several React apps on the same page. Can someone give me an example implementation for this case.